# Why can't you put Console.ReadKey() in front of the text displayed to the console, or assign Console.ReadKey() to a variable?

Tags: c#, variables, console.writeline, console.readkey

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine(" key pressed", Console.ReadKey());
  }
}
```

this code works and has no errors but

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadKey(), " key pressed");
  }
}
```

This doesn't work and I get an error

> Error CS1502: the best overload method match for 'System.Console.WriteLine(string, object)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Error CS1503: Argument '#1' cannot convert 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' expression to type 'string'

I'm new to C# so I don't know much about the language (only ever used Python before), but in Python, I would write this code as

```
keyPressed = input("Type a key(s) ")
print(keyPressed, "is the key(s) you pressed")
```

I also can't just assign ReadKey() to a variable

```
var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("the key you pressed was {0}", keyPressed);
```

For the block of code above, I want to have whatever key the user presses stored inside the variable keyPressed, but it doesn't work.

My question is why can't you put `Console.ReadKey()` in front of the text I want displayed on the console, or assign `Console.ReadKey()` to a variable, and how would you have whatever key the user presses assigned to a variable?

Comment: `why can't you put Console.ReadKey() in front of the text I want displayed on the console` - why did you think this is what would happen? You are calling [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_), the first argument must be a format *string*. Apparently you wanted `Console.WriteLine("{0} key pressed", Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)`.

Comment: Old(er) question that's been bumped by an edit, but if I flip the question around, does `print("is the key(s) you pressed", keyPressed)` produce the same result in Python?  I'm guessing not.  Regardless, order matters, parameters have a specific meaning, `Console.WriteLine()` is not `print()`, and neither C# nor .NET are Python (see [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the method [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8), which **have** a lot of overloads like :

- `Console.WriteLine(String)`
- `Console.WriteLine(Int64)`
- `Console.WriteLine(String, Object)`

So on and so on. But there is **no** overload :

- `Console.WriteLine(Object, String)`

And the latter is the one you are trying to use when doing `Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadKey(), " key pressed");`

Your `Console.ReadKey()` return a [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=netframework-4.8) **not** a `String` which **does not** derive from `String` or any other objects you can find in the overloads. So since it doesn't exist it cannot work and you get the error you have mentioned.

Usually you can use autocompletion to find out what are the overloads of a method or check the documentation which is mostly the best way to find and understand things.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can but you need to use it this way

```
Console.Write("Type a key: ");
var k = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine($"You have pressed {k.KeyChar}");
```